# I want google script to run a new document only if one doesn't already exist. I do not want to keep re-writing the documents

Tags: google-apps-script, overwrite

Below is the script I am using. It creates documents as forms are submitted. The script works but every time it runs it rewrites every single form. I only want it to write new documents as forms are submitted.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();
}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = 
DriveApp.getFileById('');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('')
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('RAW');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  rows.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[52]) return;
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[2]}, ${row[0]} Employee Details`, 
destinationFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[4]).toLocaleDateString();

    body.replaceText('{Q1}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{Q2}', row[3]);
```

Comment: The above script doesn't match the question wording. Is it called by a trigger or by the custom menu?

Comment: The script is "triggered" to run every time a new form is submitted. However it also currently creates a new document for those already created (previously submitted). I would like for it to see that if the is already something in the cell (link to the document) then do not rewrite it. This script takes information from a google sheet and moves that information into a document from a template.

Comment: You need to put a value in row[52] and write that column back to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Liz. If the `onOpen` function is irrelevant to what is being asked, please remove it from the question. Also review the question wording so it's clear that the `createNewGoogleDocs` is called by an installable trigger, not from the script Editor or other user interface. P.S. you could take advantage of the form submit event object to avoid having to iterate over all the rows.